# connect to MongoDB by plugin for Maven

Tags: java, mongodb, maven, jenkins

I'm trying to create with Maven connection to MongoDB in another computer, using Jenkins collection project. MongoDB on the computer is running as a service, all I need - is a plugin for Maven which can run the script to create the database and remove it.All plugins, which I found - for starting or stopping the service Mongo, which I do not need. The only more or less matching, there is that plugin http://code.google.com/p/maven-mongodb-plugin/, but the attempt to configure it for writing anything to the database failed. Tell me how this can be done. Sorry for my English, I need help, please.

Comment: How did attempts to configure this plugin fail?  What configuration did you change and what errors did you get?  The plugin looks like it's doing the correct thing at a glance so without knowing how it failed for you, it's hard to suggest what you should change.